# How to use data backed by API instead of ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I would like to be able to use data with searchkick that is not via ActiveRecord / Mongoid. In my specific use case, I would like to sync data that is mapped to an API instead of a database.

For this specific use case, using an ActiveRecord supported db does not work because I have business logic that is encapsulated at the API layer for another service that is not written to the db but calculated at request time. So I'm currently in a place where we need to duplicate business logic in the searchkick layer or precompute all business logic and save it to the db.

So the best solution I see currently is to implement the ActiveRecord interface and have it fetch from my API but I was wondering if anyone had a better idea since that interface is relatively large.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to checkout one of the following.

https://github.com/flexirest/flexirest

https://github.com/rails/activeresource